# How to autocomplete TypeScript interface with JetBrains WebStorm

Tags: typescript, autocomplete, phpstorm, webstorm

I have a `Job` interface in a separate file:

```
export interface Job {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    employerId: string;
    location: {
        address: string;
        city: string;
        state: string;
        zip: string;
    };
    createdAt: string;
}
```

and when I want to use it..

```
const mockJob: Job = {}
```

Is there a quick way of having all the properties be displayed for me ready to type in the values in WebStorm?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, getting annoying typing them all out.

Comment: add a TS compiler to your IDE like written here https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/03/how-to-compile-typescript-in-webstorm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you like properties stubs being auto-generated? No, there is no such possibility now, this feature will only be available in 2018.1 (see [WEB-29614](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29614) and linked tickets). 
But you can hit `Ctrl+Space` within braces and choose properties from completion

Comment: Yup, that looks like what I'm looking for. Ah well, all I can do is wait. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This now works.

**On Mac**

Use <kbd>⌘N</kbd>:

```
let obj = MyInterface{/* ⌘N here */};
```

There, you can hit enter on **Implement Members**. <kbd>⌘A</kbd> to select all of them.